# How to find the domain and range of a function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the domain and range of each function:

$f(x) = \sqrt{(x^2-3x)}$

Answer (score 2):

The domain is the easier of the two to find. You’re looking for the set of all real numbers $x$ such that $f(x)$ ‘makes sense’. Finding $f(x)$ requires you to take the square root of $x^2-3x$, and in the real numbers you can do that if and only if $x^2-3x\ge 0$. That reduces the problem of finding the domain of $f$ to the problem of solving the inequality $x^2-3x\ge 0$.

Finding the range of $f$ is then a matter of finding the set of possible ‘output’ values $f(x)$. It’s helpful at this point to look at the graph of $y=f(x)$ to get an idea.

Suppose, for instance, that the domain turned out to be the interval $[4,6]$. As $x$ ranges over that interval, what do the values of $f(x)$ do? The intermediate quantity $x^2-3x=x(x-3)$ increases from $4$ to $18$, so $f(x)$ increases from $\sqrt4=2$ to $\sqrt{18}=3\sqrt2$. If the domain of $f$ really were $[4,6]$, the range of $f$ would be $[2,3\sqrt2]$. Neither of these is correct, but the example should give you a handle in finding the actual range of $f$ once you’ve found the domain.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$ x^2 - 3x \ge 0 $$

Can you see why?

Answer (score 0):

$\sqrt{y}$ is *defined* only when $y\geqslant0$. So, to find the *domain* of $f(x) = \sqrt{(x^2-3x)}$, we need to solve the following inequality: $$\sqrt{(x^2-3x)}\geqslant0$$
Since both sides are positive, we can square them which will give: $$x^2-3x\geqslant0\Rightarrow x(x-3)\geqslant0$$
Now solve the inequality and transform it into a range.